# ¿Cómo puedo validar si una variable que contiene el nombre de un fichero termina en ".txt"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para restringir el tipo de archivo que recibe como parámetro, es decir, cómo puedo hacer para que si no es un archivo .txt el que se introduce, termine el programa.

Aquí está lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test "$1" = "" ; then 
    echo "Hay que introducir un argumento que sea un archivo de texto para poder ejecutar este guión"
    exit 1
else
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        echo "El fichero sí existe."
        cuenta=$(cat "$1" | wc -m)
        echo Hay $cuenta palabras en $1
    else 
        echo "El argumento no es un fichero" 
        exit 2
    fi
fi
```

Para ejecutar el script hago lo siguiente:

```
$ chmod 777 cuatro.sh
$ ./cuatro.sh
```

Comment: Por cierto, veo que usas `wc -m` para contar palabras. Nótese que no hace esto, sino contar caracteres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente extrae la extensión del fichero y luego mira su valor:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Consigue la extensión eliminando todo el texto hasta el último punto
extension="${1##*.}"

if [ $extension != "txt" ]; then #si no termina en .txt
    echo "El fichero ha de ser de texto (terminado en .txt)"
    exit 2
fi
```

Estoy usando aquí la comparación `[` en lugar de `[[`, pues esta última es solamente propia de Bash y la primer es más genérica al estar [definida por POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Answer (score 2):

Si simplemente quieres mirar la extensión del archivo puedes usar una expresión regular:

```
if ! [[ $1 =~ ^.+\.txt$ ]]; then #si no termina en .txt
    echo "El fichero ha de ser de texto (terminado en .txt)"
    exit 2
fi
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Esto era lo que buscaba pero no sabía muy bien como usar los metacaracteres para hacerlo!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu pregunta fue:

cómo puedo hacer para restringir el tipo de archivo

**Si sólo miras la extensión**, puedes recibir cualquier fichero renombrado que no sea un fichero de texto...

Puedes realizar algo parecido a esto:

```
#!/bin/bash
#...
# suponemos que ya hemos recibido como parametro el nombre del fichero
# Comprobamos su tipo...
# ...
tipo=`file $1 |awk -F ": " '{print $2}'`
if [ "$tipo" = "ASCII text" ] ; then
    echo "$1 SI es fichero de TEXTO"
    # ... acciones ...
else
    echo "$1 NO es fichero de Texto"
    # ... acciones ...
fi
```

Además puedes "revisar" otros tipos de ficheros...
Puedes ver la lista completa con:

```
file -l
```

Comment: Interesante. Sería bueno puntualizar que es mucho mejor usar `$( )` para ejecutar un comando en `tipo=$( ... )` pues los backticks están [_desaconsejadas_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23102/1674).

Comment: He visto muchos scripts antiguos con los backticks, pero creo que por convenio no se deben usar por los problemas que pueda dar con los otros intérpretes, no?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres una forma sencilla puedes usar el comando **file**

```
file
```

Ejemplo (tengo 2 ficheros)

El primero:

```
fichero1
#!/bin/bash
echo "Soy un script de bash"
```

El segundo:

```
fichero2
Soy solo
un simple
fichero de texto
```

Si realizo un 'file' sobre ellos obtengo:

```
$ file fichero*
fichero1: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
fichero2: ASCII text
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo lo incorpora al script? ¿No sería más fácil mirar la extensión del archivo?

Comment: Es que has preguntado:cómo puedo hacer para restringir el tipo de archivo

Comment: No, no, yo no he preguntado algo, no soy el autor de la pregunta :) Tu respuesta puede ser útil, pero implicaría parsear la salida de `file`, etc.

Comment: Perdon.. me confundi al responder...